# how to programmatically select an option as the selected option?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have an html that look like this

```
<select class="form-control"
    name="settings.provider"
    id="settings.provider"
    ng-model="settings.provider"
required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Provider</option>
    <option value="thisProvider">thisProvider</option>
</select>
```

How will I programmatically select "thisProvider" as the selected option?

I tried this but it isn't working:

$scope.settings.provider = "thisProvider";

Comment: Hello, did my answer work for you? If not let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If your options are not bound with an ng-repeat, you can bind each option to setting in your controller using ng-selected (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected).  In your controller, you create a boolean like $scope.thisProviderSelected for each option, then set it to true for the option you want selected.

```
<select class="form-control" name="settings.provider" id="settings.provider"
ng-model="settings.provider" required>
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Provider</option>
    <option value="thisProvider" ng-selected="thisProviderSelected">thisProvider</option>
</select>
```

A better way would probably be use ng-repeat and to add an isSelected to each item in the list.  That way if your list changes, you would automatically get any new items.

Answer (score 1):

```js
 
document.getElementById('settings.provider').value = 'thisProvider';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control"
    name="settings.provider"
    id="settings.provider"
    ng-model="settings.provider"
required>
    <option value="" disabled>Select Provider</option>
    <option value="thisProvider">thisProvider</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

Create Event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="selectItemByValue(document.getElementById('settings.provider'),2)">change</a>
```

**JavaScript Function**:

```
function selectItemByValue(elmnt, value){

  for(var i=0; i < elmnt.options.length; i++)
  {
    if(elmnt.options[i].value === value) {
      elmnt.selectedIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Break out of your loop, once you have found the selected value.

### Solution 2:

```
var Person_ID = 2;
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('personlist').value=Person_ID;">change</a>
```